# WordPress custom theme going to 404.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a custom theme with (for now) nothing special in it. My functions.php only contains an action hook to `wp_enqueue_scripts` and I have the following files:

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

index.php

```
<?php
get_header(); ?>
INDEX
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

archive.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
ARCHIVE
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

404.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
404
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
# WP Basics
//include_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/functions/menus.php" );
include_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . "/functions/scripts.php" );
```

Now I have the following issue, when I go to the front page it shows the correct page, but when I got to any other page, archive, or what so ever it ends in the 404.php.

I did check the following:

1. Disable all plugins (no result)
2. Enable default theme (twenty-seventeen, everything is fine)
3. Permalinks are on "/%postname%/" when I set it to "plain" everything works
4. Check if there is a .htaccess somewhere where it doesn't belong (isn't)
5. Check if filenames are correct (they are)

So needless to say I'm really stuck, I have made several custom theme's and never had this issue before. Does anyone have any idea?

Kind regards,

Augus

Comment: Where is your single.php?

Comment: single.php has the same contents as the rest (like index.php). But for the WP template hierachy it shouldn't matter cause it would default back to index.php and not 404.php.

Comment: Try going to Settings > Permalinks and just save the form. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't work. I got a fix and posted it as an answer. Thanks to anyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing style.css file in your theme as in your question you haven't mention style.css.

And style.css is most required file to create the theme in wordpress so please add style.css in your theme and it will work for sure.

Comment: Yes, Style.css is required but it will not display 404 if  missing style.css

Comment: Yea sorry style.css is also there, so that isn't the problem im afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so i fixed it, thanks for all the help.

I added a rewrite rule which wasn't correct, then i deleted it again. But somehow this rewrite didn't go away and was only active for my theme.

I was under the assumption that when i saved the permalinks again the rewrite rules were flushed, but this wasn't the case. So i added the following snippet to my functions.php and it worked.

```
add_action( 'init', 'shoe_flush_rewrite_rules' );


function shoe_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

**Remember to delete this snippet when everything works again, cause it doesn't need to be run everytime.**